# В каком случае может быть пустой язык в браузере?

Tags: php

Речь идёт о переменной:

```
$_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]
```

Наблюдаю что иногда она пустая у некоторых посетителей. У себя проверил и в обычном режиме и в режиме инкогнито эта переменная не пустая.

Вопрос: у обычного посетителя сайта (человека) может быть эта переменная пустая в каком-то естественном случае? Или же это всё же признак робота или того, что человек намеренно её скрывает?

Comment: Обычно барузер ее заполняет сам. Чтобы проверить боты или нет, можно адреса с пустым заголовком фоном прогонять по geoip и выяснить кому они принадлежат. Либо собирать их куда-то и проверять выборочно вручную, например тут https://tools.keycdn.com/geo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

И человек может скрыть и может быть признак робота. Но робот может не просто иметь этот параметр, но и рандомно его менять, как и все прочие к стати, вроде реферера, юзер агента и т.д. Если у вас задача отделить юзера от бота - куда шире проблема на самом деле и так с ходу её не решить